# Wildfly 8 : Listener in web.xml not called

Tags: web.xml

I have an application which worked in GlasshFish and that I want to migrate Wildfly 8.

I successfully deployed the application in Wildfly but the listener present in web.xml is not called.

web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ContactAccountActivation</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>ca.evision.eAwards.servlet.ContactAccountActivation</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.fero.web.tags.LoadMetaModelListner</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ContactAccountActivation</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ContactAccountActivation</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/pages/loginForm.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
     <session-config>
        <session-timeout>15</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

I tested calling this string from an other sample application web.xml and it works correctly. I use the Netbeans 8 lite IDE.

Thanks for your help.